# Excel files, open (allow time to perform calculations), and saving changes - maybe shutil will work?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, shutil

I have created a script to write data into multiple excel files, these files then perform the calculation based on the data entered, a next script then reads the results from these files. My problem is that I currently have to open and save each excel file manually for the calculation to take place before reading out the data. (I have checked the excel refresh settings, not the problem.)

Is there a way of automating a process that opens each file, and effectively click save so save the updated calculations in each sheet? (I have used pandas to read, write, and save the excel files, so it isn't the problem of the formula being seen instead of the values.)

shutil looks like it should be the right tool for the job, but I am stuck in trying to replicate the manual "open", "click save" and then close process - maybe there is a better way? Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

(Edited to add that I am running python3 on an Ubuntu subsystem on my windows box, so I have read about people encountering this but they had a windows based work around that doesn't translate to the Ubuntu windows mix.)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Python script update the data of each spreadsheet.
Step 2:  Python script launches Excel passing somefile.xlsm  in the command line. some file.xlsm contains a macro that opens and closes all Excel files then exits.
Step 3: Python script will resume once the shelled Excel process exits.

```
Sub OpenSaveAllFiles()
    LoopThroughFiles "c:\pathtofolder"
End Sub

Sub LoopThroughFiles (FolderPath)
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Set wb = Workbooks.open(ofile)
        wb.Save()
        wb.Close()
    Next oFile

    Application.Quit()
End Sub
```

I did not try the macro (typed it from my mobile). Give it a shot and advise.

Comment: Hi Tarik, thank you for commenting on my post.

Yes, step 1 I have the script that updates the spreadsheet.
Step 2 is what I am trying to make, something that opens and closes the xlsx (not xlsm?) sheets. 

The problem is that I do not know how to create step 2 and which is what I thought perhaps shutil would work for? I unfortunately am not able to understand enough of your suggestion.

Step 3 works.

Comment: The xlsm file is the macro Excel file who's job will be to open and save each Excel file. The m stands for macro. I will revise my answer with some code.